# Will returning two 1/2" lines to 3/4" get a volume return?

Tags: plumbing

I am converting a seperate shower and tub to a large walk-in spa shower. The cold water at the existing shower is 3/4" (and branched off to the tub,shower & toilet in 1/2"). The new shower valve system is 3/4" so I am good there with just a bit of re-plumbing. The problem is with the hot plumbing. The plumbing is all under slab and the 3/4" part of it is non accessible. The tub and shower hot branch off a 3/4" to 1/2" under the slab somewhere. The access between the two 1/2" hot water lines is configured in a way as I could bring them together at the new shower wall. If I were to bring them together with a T that fed them to a 3/4" line to the new valve would I get my flow back from the 1/2" drops? I am installing 6 body sprayers and need the flow. I did get sprayers with the lowest rate possible (only 1.5 gpm per head). So basically, if I have X amount of volume in a 3/4" pipe and reduce it into two 1/2" pipes then bring both 1/2" pipes back to 3/4" will I retrieve my volume? It would work kind of like a loop would it not?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your flow rate, and the length of your run. The short answer is you won't have a noticeable pressure drop for a relatively short run.

Using this [table](http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/pressure-loss-plastic-pipes-d_404.html), the nominal inside diameters of the pipes actually give you a slightly greater cross sectional area from the two 1/2" pipes (0.608 sq. in. vs 0.533 sq. in.).

However, the head loss is still greater for the two 1/2" pipes. For the 9 GPM you'll need for the body jets, you'll have a loss of about 15.8 ft/100 ft pipe on the 3/4". For the 4.5 GPM you'll need through each 1/2" pipe, you'll have a loss of 16.9 ft/100 ft pipe.*

This comes out to a loss of 6.85 psi per 100 feet of pipe for the 3/4" pipe, or 7.33 psi per 100 feet of pipe for the two 1/2" pipes. You'll have to add another 15.6' of equivalent footage for the two extra T and elbow fittings as well.

*Note: I linearly interpolated these values, but the head loss curve is NOT linear. So not an EXACT answer, but probably close enough.

Comment: ...and for considerably less than 100 feet of pipe (including the extra fittings) in a bathroom, you'll have a very hard time **noticing** a differential loss of 0.48PSI/100 feet...

Comment: @Ecnerwal, true, I forgot to directly mention it depends on the length of the run as well. For a short run, it shouldn't matter.

Answer (score -1):

No, it won't make volume. Two half inch equals one inch of flow and the 3/4 inch is smaller and it will not let you get the same volume. It will flow faster, but less volume.

Comment: You're forgetting that area increases by the square of the radius. Plus, the nominal inside diameters of PVC aren't exactly 1/2" and 3/4".

Comment: Your 3/4" pipe will regulate the volume, so he'll end up with the same volume he has now.  Because, you're basically not changing anything: you're taking one 3/4" pipe, splitting it into two 1/2" pipes and then merging the two 1/2" pipes back to one 3/4" pipe. This should make the water volume the same

Comment: I don't think you understand what I'm saying. Your statement of "Two half inch equals one inch of flow" is 100% wrong.

Comment: Help me to understand so I know for future reference. Also, I must have missed where he said he was using PVC.

Comment: The cross-sectional area of a pipe increases with the square of the radius. A=pi*r^2. A literal 3/4" pipe has a cross-sectional area of 0.44 sq. inches, and a literal 1/2" pipe has a cross-sectional area of 0.20 sq. inches. Nominal diameter actually varies a bit from the specified diameter. Pressure loss is also not a linear relationship with diameter.

Comment: So will I pick up the flow rate of the 3/4" if I bring the 2 1/2" branches together to a 3/4" into my temp control valve? Meaning will I get the same output from the temp control valve if I feed both 1/2" branches into it? There is just no way to get to the 3/4" main under the concrete and vanities somewhere. But I have access to the last two 1/2" runs of 5" or so from the end of the 3/4". One of them is of no use to me unless I can bring it and the other together into a 1/2"x3/4"x1/2" T and feed the valve with 3/4", hopefully to regain the original volume of the 3/4" before the two 1/2" runs

Comment: You guys are beating me up! LOL! Bettersex13 is on the same track I am. And he is right, I never said what type pipe I am using. I am actually putting in PEX off the original copper. I am a novice at plumbing but I believe that a loss of only 0.04 sq. in. by combining the two 1/2" is better than a loss of 0.20 by just running the one 1/2" as stated by Doresoom. The only 1" involved is the street main to the house that drops to 3/4". So do we all agree that as stated by Bettersex13, the 3/4" will regulate the volume pretty close if I merge the two 1/2" into the valve with a 1/2"x3/4"x1/2" Tee?

Comment: So Doresoom.... my statement doesn't imply two 1/2" equal the same as 1" of flow. What I'm thinking is that the two 1/2" pipes will return the flow of the 3/4" pipe they originate from if I bring them back to a 3/4 again. Mind you neither of the 1/2" branches have any other branches and neither will be used between their original branch off and where I tie them back together. It's really that simple. One 3/4" split to two 1/2" and brought back together at 3/4" should maintain original flow?

Comment: @prowlercrew, Sorry, I didn't get the notification you posted on this answer. You've probably already got things all finished by now. As I stated in my answer, you should have a slight pressure drop (probably under a few PSI) if you run the two 1/2" lines. That should be an acceptable trade-off. (I'm not sure where you got the idea that I recommended running only one 1/2" line. I never said that.)